# Changing the name of the terms in ggally::ggcoef

Tags: r, ggally

Given the following example

```
iris_fat <- iris %>% mutate(is_fat = factor(ifelse(Sepal.Width * Petal.Width > 6 ,"fat", "not_fat")))
reg <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + is_fat, data = iris_fat)
  GGally::ggcoef(reg)
```

[image]

How can I change the name of the term `is_fatnot_fat` to something else.

Comment: `GGally::ggcoef(reg)+
    labs(y = c("(Intercept)", "is_fat", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Width"))` is not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad on the earlier comment, didn't read it carefully.

ggcoef creates a list, just like the other ggplot functions.  The first element, data, is a dataframe in which `term` maps to the y-axis.  If you're curious, try `str(test_plot$data)` or examine it in RStudio

```
test_plot <- ggcoef(reg)
test_plot$data$term <- c("(Intercept)", "is_fat", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Width")
```